# Azure SQL Deleted Database cannot restore because of region restriction

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is there any way to change the region for a Azure SQL server/database from one geographical region to another region?

I have a deleted database which I cannot restore as I get "MSDN subscriptions are restricted from provisioning in this region. Please choose a different region. For exceptions to this rule please contact Microsoft Support."

The Server was originally setup in US-West region with a VS MSDN Subscription.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the ways to change region from Azure SQL database, there are mutiple options -

1. [Configure active geo-replication for Azure SQL Database in the Azure portal and initiate failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-portal)
2. [Copy an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy)
3. [Export an Azure SQL database to a BACPAC file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export)
4. [Set up SQL Data Sync (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync)

However, based on the error if there is limitation on specific region and you have strict requirement to have database in same region you may need to work with Azure support on it.

Comment: Yes as the database is showing in the deleted database and i'm trying to restore it first  before moving it to a region that doesn't have the restriction.   As the database isnt in a non-deleted state it doesnt appear that I can back it up, copy it or really do anything with it at the moment.

Comment: Ended up being a MS issues about how this was switched over from one subscription to another.  They fixed it and everything then worked as expected.